# How do I speed up this regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have a large Pandas dataframe (about 3 million rows). One of the columns contains strings. I need to remove a set of substrings from the column, as well as count some characters, so I am making use of the `re` package.
I put this all into a function like this:

```
def process(s):    
   s = re.sub("[\r\n\t]", "", s)
   s = re.sub("\S+\\\(pwsh|sqlps|sqltoolsps|powershell|powershell_ise)\.exe|^(pwsh|sqlps|sqltoolsps|powershell|powershell_ise)(\.exe)*", "", s)
   obf_symbol_count = len(re.split("(['@%^,;:=&+\"\(\{\)\}`!\*\./\?_\[\]\|<>~$])", s))
   nonobf_symbol_count = len(re.split("([^'@%^,;:=&+\"\(\{\)\}`!\*\./\?_\[\]\|<>~$])", re.sub("\s", "", s)))
```

At first I was using `.apply()` to process the column, but it was very slow.
I thought it might go faster to use

```
df['col1'].str.replace("[\r\n\t]", "")
df['col1'].str.replace("\S+\\\(pwsh|sqlps|sqltoolsps|powershell|powershell_ise)\.exe|^(pwsh|sqlps|sqltoolsps|powershell|powershell_ise)(\.exe)*", "")
```

but this didn't help much.
How can I speed up the process?

Comment: Have you considered compiling your regex? That should get you some performance gain but all that backtracing it may still not be enough.

Comment: `"\S+\\\(pwsh|sqlps|sqltoo...` - that pattern has unmatched parentheses - maybe one to many escapes? --> `"\S+\\(pwsh|sqlps|sqltoo...`

Comment: Try `^\S*?\\(pwsh|sqlps|sqltoolsps|powershell|powershell_ise)\.exe`

Comment: @Thefourthbird is that expression exactly equivalent?